# TTS Class: How to TTS chinese Pinyin?

Tags: android, cjk, text-to-speech

Is there a way to TTS output Pinyin via the tts class (in the correct tone)?

I tried SVOX and Pico...

I have a database where different words are stored in a form like
Ni3
Hao3

I tried:
- Ni3Hao3 -> result: NiSanHaoSan (San means 3).
- Nín hǎo -> result: N  i  n  h o  (Only speaking letters, missing the a)

I thought about using a table givin to every word - sound combination one chinese utf sign. But that seems to be absurd.

Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: Any progress with this?

Answer (score 0):

U might try the jtts which depends on espeak.